# TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview, datacontext, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a class SceneNode which contains a ObservableCollection.  I want the entire tree to show up, however I can't seem to get this to work with databinding.  Everything works perfectly if I just add the root to the trees items.

```
class SceneNode
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ObserveableCollection<SceneNode> ChildrenNodes{get;set;}
    ....
}
class Scene
{
    public SceneNode Nodes{get;set;}
}
```

So I bind the Scene to the Trees data context and the following is my trees xaml

```
<TreeView MinHeight="250" ItemsSource={Binding Path=Nodes} >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SceneNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildSceneNodes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,10,0,10" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>                
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Behind the scenes I before the control with the tree is shown I bind its data context

```
sceneTree.Tree.DataContext = theScene;
```

Nothing shows, however if instead of binding the data I do

```
sceneTree.Tree.Items.Add( theScene.Nodes );
```

The tree will show and I can add and remove nodes and this activity reflects in the TreeView.

Comment: To solve this I made a new property in the Scene object that just returns a new ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the ItemsSource property recive a Collection and you are making the binding to a SceneNode, that is not a collection. This problem will be solved making the binding to the ChildrenNodes property:

```
    <TreeView x:Name="treeView" MinHeight="250" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes.ChildrenNodes}" >
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfBackgroundWorkerQuestion:SceneNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildrenNodes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,10,0,10" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: i tested this here, maybe could be that the classes need to be public, also, the Bindings need quotes Ex ItemsSources="{Binding...

Comment: also in my code i make a mistake and i write DataType="{x:Type WpfBackgroundWorkerQuestion:SceneNode}", instide of  DataType="{x:Type local:SceneNode}"